# Cannot access private variable from constructor - not in scope (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, sdl-2

I'm creating a simple game in SDL2 and learning about C++ classes, however I'm having difficulty with private variables and class constructors. I'm attempting to access an `SDL_Texture` that is defined as a private variable and modify it within the constructor.

Upon compilation the code below causes the following error:

`In constructor 'PlayerShip::PlayerShip(SDL_Texture*)':
|5| error: 'ShipSprite' was not declared in this scope`

Header file (PlayerShip.h):

```
#ifndef PLAYERSHIP_H
#define PLAYERSHIP_H

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

class PlayerShip
{
    public:
        PlayerShip(SDL_Texture * tex);
    private:
        SDL_Texture * ShipSprite = nullptr; //The variable/texture I want to modify
};
#endif
```

CPP file (PlayerShip.cpp)

```
#include "PlayerShip.h"

PlayerShip::PlayerShip(SDL_Texture * tex) //ctor
{
    ShipSprite = tex; //This needs to change the private variable above. However "ShipSprite" is apparently not in scope.
}
```

It is defined in the header, however I'm not sure why it won't access it even though it's inside the class. I've tried searching for solutions to this problem, however the ones I found were not related to my issue.

On top of this, I've tried changing `ShipSprite = tex;` to the following but with no success:
`PlayerShip::ShipSprite = tex;` and
`this->ShipSprite = tex;`

Any ideas for this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the *only* error the compiler gives you?

Comment: It sounds like you might have more than one file named `PlayerShip.h`

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes that's the only error I get, and I've checked for duplicate files and couldn't find any.

Comment: I must ask, what is the usefulness of the initializer to `nullptr` if the only constructor to the class immediately tosses that value in favor of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you don't define the include guard (`#ifndef PLAYERSHIP_H`) somewhere else.

Also, check the output of minGW, which files it uses, maybe your assumptions are wrong? You can also do quick and dirty debug things like introducing a syntax error in your header file. If it isn't caught, the file isn't even used.

Other than that I'd suggest a few other things (unrelated to your question):

- Have a naming convention for member variables that is different from that of class names. ShipSprite could be shipSprite_, m_shipSprite, shipSprite, or what have you. (A good set of recommendations: http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html)
- If you want to initialize member variables, prefer to do so with the constructor initializer list. I.e.:
    `PlayerShip::PlayerShip(SDL_Texture * tex) : ShipSprite(tex) {
    }` The compiler might be more helpful if you are more precise in what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how recent your compiler is, it may not accept initialization of a non-static member that doesn't have integer type.  Or it may not know the keyword `nullptr`.

```
SDL_Texture * ShipSprite = nullptr;
```

Try instead

```
SDL_Texture * ShipSprite;
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to have worked. I'm still getting the same error. As for my compiler, I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.8.2 and I have the C++11 flag set.

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that I may have accidentally compiled the header file separately before I added the variable, and it left a `PlayerShip.gch` file in the same folder as my headers. GCC probably tried to use it instead of the normal header file and thus gave me that error.

Nonetheless deleting the .gch file seems to have fixed the issue for me and now the program compiles properly. Not sure how I completely missed that.

Thanks again everyone for your suggestions and help.

Edit: How do I go about closing this?

Comment: Seems like your assumptions were wrong regarding which files minGW uses, and that it would have helped to confirm this by the suggested "introducing syntax error in header file", not to mention "check output of minGW, which files it uses". All of them seem in line with my provided answer above. You could have described the solution you found as a comment to my answer, and accepted it. Alternatively, you can accept your own answer. PS: If your build system doesn't automatically update precompiled headers correctly, that's something you should fix asap, as it will give you a lot of trouble.